# how to setup yii on wamp?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to install it on my wamp server. by the following below link.

https://www.erianna.com/getting-starting-with-yii-framework-2-old

For that I have run below commands in my git shell

> git clone git@github.com:yiisoft/yii2.git /dir/to/yii2

it was downloaded yii2 in my c:/wamp/www/

than I was a execute below command.

> cd yii2/framework

than execute below command.

> php yiic.php app/create /var/www/yii2

But there is no file like yiic.php in that directory.So it was give a error like below.

> Could not open input file: yiic.php

How can I install it?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I would try with the tutorial on the Yii site itself: http://www.yiiframework.com/download/

Comment: I would try the github tutorial

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php yiic app/create /var/www/yii2
```

or

```
yiic app/create /var/www/yii2
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the Windows OS, always use absolute paths;

so, specify the absolute paths to:

php

yiic

and where you need your project to be created ( under a apache folder [www] )